# how can i close owa pane?

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-app

I have one button.
When I click on the button I want owa pane to close

`window.close ();` I tried but owa pane didn't close
after
`Office.context.mailbox.ClosePane();`  I tried but owa pane didn't close

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to hide taskpane in OWA, you can try out [Office.context.ui.closeContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=word-js-preview#closecontainer) to do that.